# React - Creating [Reducer Test] using [enzyme] + [Jest]. Login action is confusing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, reducers

Creating [Reducer Test] using [enzyme] + [Jest]. Login action is confusing.

this is my code

```
describe('IS_LOGIN_USER action', () => {
  it('should handle IS_LOGIN_USER action', () => {
    const { stateBefore, stateAfter, action } = setup(
      {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        items: {}
      },
      {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        items: {
          email: "email",
          exp: 1541424504,
          iat: 1541420904,
          name: "name",
          uid: "uid",
          url: "imageURL"
        }
      },
      isLoginUser()
    );
    expect(reducer(stateBefore, action)).toEqual(stateAfter);
  });
});
```

this is initialState object

```
export const initialState = {
    items: {},
    isLoggedIn: false,
    error: null,
    isroom: [],
    peers: [],
    inroom: true,
    webrtc: null,
    roomname: '',
    mute: false,
    length: 0,
    pass: false,
    popopen: false,
    focusid: '',
    focustitle: '',
    aboutValueTitle: '',
    alertMessage: '',
    spinner: false,
    alertBoxBottom: '',
    alertColor: '#3c29aa',
    channelAlertMessage: false,
    loggedPopUp: false,
    deleteAelrt: false,
    ieCehck: '',
    pageReturn: false
};
```

When you log in, the action changes from [isLoggedIn: false, items: {}] to [isLoggedIn: true, items: {userData}. However, the result is still Fail.
But I don't know what went wrong.

I am very sorry that the sentence is not smooth by writing the question as a translation app.

Comment: where do you get `.to()` matcher from? [jest does not provide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) such method for `expect()`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I got a mistake. It is [.toEqual()] not [.to()] Modified. Thank you.